# External tables and directory objects

Tags: oracle, external-tables

Is there any way to define the location an external table that is in a subdirectory of a named directory object? Or must an external table always be defined only pointing to a directory object? When I include the subdirectory in the LOCATION specification I get the following error:

`KUP-04076: file name cannot contain a path specification: OBIEE/GLPA_FY13.csv`

Comment: Please edit your question and show the directory names and the directory objects, and external table definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot be sub-directory.